# Finding values ​in a 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi, I have a matrix "A" (1 column) ordered in ascending order which must do the following:
Find each element of the matrix "A" that belongs within the range of 2 consecutive elements in each column of the matrix "B" (2-D) B[i,j]>= A[k] <B[i+1,j]

Calculate the sum of the averages of each value found
avg = (B[i,j] + B[i+1,j])/2 + avg

I attach the code I made but processing time is very slow when the matrix A and B are large, example: Rows(B) = 2000, Columns(B) = 500 and columns(A)=3000

Ask:
What suggestions can you reach to improve the processing speed or alternative to change the for loop with numpy???

Note:
The first row of matrix B is sorted in ascending order (B[i,j]<B[i,j+1])<B[i,j+2]) ...
Each column of matrix B is ordered in ascending order.

```
    import numpy as np
    
    A = np.array([2.1,3.2,4.5, 5.8, 6.9,7.3,8.8])
    B = np.array([[2,3,5,6],[3,4,6,7],[4,5,7,8],[5,6,8,9]])
    
    ncol = np.shape(B)[1]
    Mavg=[]
    j=0
    
    for va in np.nditer(A):
        avg =0
        for i in np.arange(ncol):
            if (va >= B[0,i]):
                try:
                    k = np.argwhere(B[:,i]>va)[0]
                except IndexError:
                    continue
                else:
                    avg = avg + (B[k-1,i] + B[k,i])/2                
            else:
                break
        Mavg = np.append(Mavg,avg)
        j = j + 1
        
    print(Mavg)
```

Comment: Exception processing is very expensive.  By comparing to the first and last elements, you can know for certain whether there is a matching pair, and eliminate the `try/except`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I changed the conditionals to remove the try/except and the execution time was reduced.